# getting the value of array key in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following line in my controller:

```
$data['faq'] = $this->faqModel->get();
```

This data print the following using the print_r

```
    Array
(
[faq] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [faqid] => 12
                [catid] => 122
                [question] => How this CMS works
                [question_en] => How this CMS works
                [answer] => How this CMS works?
                [answer_en] => How this CMS works?

                [sorder] => 2
                [visible] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [faqid] => 8
                [catid] => 121
                [question] => How does the design cost?
                [question_en] => How does the design cost?
                [answer] => How does the design cost?

                [answer_en] => How does the design cost?

                [sorder] => 1
                [visible] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

I want to use the value stored in the [catid] key, and I am trying to do something like:
$data['faq']['catid'] to get that value in the controller (I want to make another select with that value) But I am getting with this error message: Undefined index: catid

Anyone can help me to get the value of ['catid']???

Regards, Zoran

Comment: You are missing index before catid $data['faq'][0]['catid']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its 3 dimensional array u look closely there is two elements in `faq` array. You must wrote something like this: `$data['faq'][0]['catid']` or  `$data['faq'][1]['catid']`

Answer (score 1):

The way you are accessing the array is **incorrect**, you are missing the item index on the second level. The correct way to use it as you are doing would be to do

```
echo $data['faq'][0]['faqid']; //faqid of the first item
```

However, this will only show one `faqid` at a time, and it not so useful when you are iterating. So, a good way would be this way.

```
foreach($data['faq'] as $value) {
 echo $value['faqid'];
}
```